# Unity Container not Resolving my Type

Tags: inversion-of-control, unity-container

I am working in a project that is using unity. The first  element was already in the web.config and is resolving correctly. The second one (IEventRepository) was added by me. It will not resolve the type and throws an error ("Resolution of the dependency failed..")

I have 2 questions on this: 
1) What is the issue? 
2) Why does the first one have commas in it?

Thanks

```
<unity xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/practices/2010/unity">
    <container>
      <register type="Demo.IPerson, Demo.Shared.Facilities" mapTo="Person, Demo.Shared.Facilities" />
      <register type="Web.Repositories.IEventRepository" mapTo="Web.Repositories.MockEventRepository" />
    </container>
  </unity>
```

Answer (score 0):

The purpose of the commas is to separate the Type and Assembly.  For example, in the first line Demo.IPerson is the Type and this type is in the Demo.Shared.Facilities assembly.  In the second line you haven't specified both the Type and Assembly which could be the reason for the error.

The way you have configured the registration in line 2 could work if you have defined a type alias.   Have a look at [The Unity Configuration Schema](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff660914%28v=pandp.20%29.aspx#config_registerelement)